# Visualizing surfaces bounded by loops in perfect fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Let $M$ be a manifold of dimension 3 or higher with a perfect fundamental group. By the Hurewicz theorem, $H_1(M) = 0$ which means if we consider any non-trivial loop $l \in \pi_1(M)$ as a singular 1-chain, there must be a singular 2-chain, $\alpha$, whose boundary is $l$. The union of the images of the singular simplices of $\alpha$ will be a surface in $M$ which we can perturb to an immersed surface $S_\alpha$ with $\partial \alpha = l$. This surface cannot be a disk because then we could contract $l$ along it which would remove $l$ from $\pi_1(M)$. My question is what does $S_\alpha$ look like? Is it some sort of Mobius band?

Comment: Do you know what an oriented surface with one boundary component looks like?

Comment: I would have thought a disk or some sort of punctured torus. Obviously it can't be a disk, but I have trouble seeing how it can be a punctured torus.

Comment: Do you mean you cannot visualize the once punctured torus?

Comment: No, I can imagine a punctured torus embedded in a 3-manifold. My objection is that if the torus' central hole does not coincide with a 1-hole in the 3-manifold then we could add a cap to the central hole and the punctured torus becomes a punctured sphere which is a disk, and our loop becomes trivial again. If the central hole does coincide with a 1-hole then $H_1(M)$ is non zero, which contradicts the original hypothesis. The heart of my objection is that I don't see how $S_{\alpha}$ can fail to contribute any 1-homology to M and yet also not be a disk.

Comment: I see: The point is that both generators of the punctured torus can bound their own punctured tori, et cetera. You can easily build a CW complex this way by inductively adding punctured tori. The fact that there are finite complexes like this is indeed not easy to visualize.

Comment: So tell me if I have this right, in something like the poincare homology 3-sphere we could find a tree of these punctured tori, which extends infinitely, and provides a surface to bound each of the generating loops? I know this space can be visualized as the dodecahedron with opposite faces identified, I'm wondering if one could draw the first few stages of these surfaces inside it.

Comment: Yes, except the surfaces are not necessarily embedded. I do not know how to draw this. You can try to draw immersed surfaces in the genus 2 surface which express the double commutator $[[x,y],[z,w]]$. Good luck with this!

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my confusion, I've been wondering about this since I got interested in Casson handles last year.